# How to show price close to a round figure without decimal point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, ecmascript-6, e-commerce

i am doing an ecommerce project.

Regular price is $549

12.96% is OFF

if i minus 12.96% from $549

Sale price becomes $477.8496

**As it can be seen in below screenshot.**

[image]

I want to show sale price close to a round figure either it should be $477 or $478

here is the code.

```
{item.price - item.price *  item.discountPercentage/100 }
```

Answer (score 1):

let price = 477.8496;

let formattedPrice = Math.round(price);

Adjust the variable names and values based on your specific use case. The key idea is to use a rounding function (like round() in Python or Math.round() in JavaScript) to round the price to the nearest whole number and then format it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can round off the decimal values with **price.toFixed()**. You can also pass a integer argument to round up to the number of decimal places. (ex: **price.toFixed(2**)).

**parseInt(price)** is another way to eliminate the decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

***Math.floor()** is a JavaScript method that returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.*

**Math.floor(477.8496);**      // returns 477

***Math.ceil()** function returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a given number.*

**Math.ceil(477.8496);**       // returns 478

Answer (score 0):

To round the number `477.888` either up to `488` or down to `477` in JavaScript, you can use the `Math.ceil()` method to round up or the `Math.floor()` method to round down. Here's how you can achieve both:

1. Round up to `488`:

```js
var roundedUp = Math.ceil(477.888);
console.log(roundedUp); // Output: 478
```

2. Round down to `477`:

```js
var roundedDown = Math.floor(477.888);
console.log(roundedDown); // Output: 477
```

Answer (score 0):

`You should try Math.round(discountedPrice) for achieving the rounded value of discounted price`.

Here I am sharing [codeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/math-round-qr57xj?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A7%2C1)

```
const discountedPrice =
    regularPrice - (regularPrice * discountPercentage) / 100;

  const roundedDiscountedPrice = Math.round(discountedPrice);
```